# Using a Model with "general purpose" fields to model inheritance

Tags: database, django, django-models

I am currently kidding around on how to model something using Django. The basic situation is that I have an object that should serve as a `chassis` and provide some `sockets`. Then there are loads of different `modules` that are placed on the `sockets` of a `chassis`. I would like to model these different `modules` as distinct classes in Django, but use a common class on the database layer, possibly involving some generic fields.

So the database model might look something like this:

```
class Module(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Or is there a better way to annotate a type?
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128) 
    string1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    string2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    int1 = models.IntegerField()

# Some kind of engine class that derives from Module
# but does nothing else then "mapping" the generic
# fields to something sensible

class Socket(models.Model):
    is_on = models.ForeignKey(Chassis)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Connection(models.Model):
    chassis = models.ForeignKey(Chassis)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    via = models.ForeignKey(Socket)

class Chassis(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    modules= models.ManyToManyField(Module, through='Connection')

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Of course I wouldn't want to spoil my logic with this denormalization. Thats why I hinted for some kind of `engine` class that should use the Module table, but provide "logical" getters and setters, effectively mapping data like "Horsepower" to "int1".

So my questions are basicly:

- Is what I am doing reasonable with Django? Or is there a better (possibly built in) way to deal with this?
- Would it be possible to construct the correct type, the one providing the wrapper methods for the denormalized model, depending on the `Module.type` field automatically?

Comment: Can you clarify your second question regarding Module.type a bit. I do not get it.

Comment: I would like to automatically constructed a class, possibly derived from the model class, that is stated in the `type` field. Or by any other means "simply" construct the "right" class, the one containing the wrapper methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is what I am doing reasonable with Django?

The general idea is okay, but the denormalization may make your queries less than optimal. The standard solution would be to subclass `Module` for each type of module; this would create a `module` table plus a table per module type with the type-specific stuff. This, of course, assumes you won't be creating or deleting module types at runtime.

That said, there are some issues with your models:

```
class Module(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Or is there a better way to annotate a type?
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128) 
    string1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    string2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    int1 = models.IntegerField()
```

Normally, `type` would get normalized to save space:

```
class ModuleType(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Any other type-specific parameters.

class Module(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ModuleType, related_name="modules")
    string1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    string2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    int1 = models.IntegerField()
```

---

```
class Socket(models.Model):
    is_on = models.ForeignKey(Chassis)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Connection(models.Model):
    chassis = models.ForeignKey(Chassis)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    via = models.ForeignKey(Socket)

class Chassis(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    sockets = m
    modules= models.ManyToManyField(Model, through='Socket')
```

`Chassis` is a mess. You didn't define `sockets`, wrote `Model` where you probably want `module`, and `through` should probably refer to `Connection` (a `through` model has to have `ForeignKey`s to both ends of the link). But from your description, I get the far simpler:

```
class Socket(models.Model):
    chassis = models.ForeignKey(Chassis, related_name="sockets")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Is `type` a ModuleType? If so, use a ForeignKey.
    # If not, create a SocketType model.
    type = models.___
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, related_name="sockets")

class Chassis(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    sockets = models.IntegerField()
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Socket)
```

With a better description of what you're modeling, this can be refined further. For example, I'm not sure a ManyToMany is what you want. You may need to split the *design* of a chassis (i.e. things common to all instances of a given kind of chassis, including its sockets) from the *instances* of that chassis (which would reference the design, and have another table mapping sockets to modules).

---

> Would it be possible to construct the correct type depending on the Module.type field automatically?

That's the Factory design pattern. In Python, you'd implement it as a dictionary of constructors:

```
class Module(models.model):
    # ...
    CONSTRUCTORS = {}

    @staticmethod
    def register_constructor(type_name, constructor):
        Module.CONSTRUCTORS[type_name] = constructor

    def construct(self):
        return Module.CONSTRUCTORS[self.type.name](self)
```

I don't think you need a specific engine class; the various module classes will suffice.

Comment: Ouch, sorry for all those wrong types flying around ... Doesn't seem to be a strong day of mine.

Comment: Oh, and your are right regarding the further refinement I need to to regarding the actual instances. Thanks for your great answer, I have something to work with now :) Oh, and I updated the messy code, hope its ok now.

Comment: Something else to note in your original schema: both `Socket` and `Connection` have `ForeignKey`s to `Chassis`, and `Connection` has a `ForeignKey` to `Socket`. This triangle-shaped link is a good indication that you have a redundant `ForeignKey`, in this case the one in `Connection`: `Connection.chassis` is really a duplicate of `Connection.via.is_on`. Eliminating `Connection.chassis` reduces `Connection` to just the two `ForeignKey`s needed for the `ManyToManyField`, which means you can get rid of `through=Connection` and thus `Connection`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define an abstract base class you can do the following:

```
class Module(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128) 
    string1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    string2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    int1 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SpecificModule(Module):
     subClassField = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I would recommend to read [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) of the documentation as it is a perfectly good starting point for dealing with inheritance and abstract classes.

You could also define the parent Module class without `class Meta: abstract = True` . The only difference is that with `abstract = True` all fields of the class `SpecificModule` and all the fields of the abstract Module parent class will be created in the subclass table for the class SpecificModule, whereas with no `abstract = True` definition a table for the class Module will be created, having all "generic" fields available in the Module table, and all sub-class specific fields in the table for the class SpecificModule.

Edit: In reply to the question regarding relationship between parent and child.

As an implicit one-to-one field is created in the subclass table ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations)), you can get the child object using this query.

```
#get the parent
parent = Module.objects.get(name="my first module")
#this is possible
print parent.name
>>> "my first module"
#this is not possible
print parent.subClassField
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'subClassField'
#get the corresponding child
child = SpecificModule.objects.get(module_ptr_id=parent.pk)
#finally we can print the value
print child.subClassField
```

I think there should be also a default related_name be created by Django, but not sure which one it is.

Please note that an implicit one-to-one relationship from parent to child is only created in the `abstract=False` case. Nevertheless if `abstract = True` you will not have the abstract parent available as an object, since it is abstract..

Comment: Would I be able to have a foreign key to the abstract baseclass and "get" the correct instance when putting this in a model definition?

Comment: Yes, in the abstract = False case. I updated my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: The nice thing about the non-abstract case is that, if you don't need any module-specific stuff, you can just work with the `Module` model. I'm not sure you can have `ForeignKey`s to `Module` in the abstract case (needed by `Socket`). This could also make it hard to run a query across multiple types of modules.

Comment: It is not possible to set a ForeignKey to an abstract class (just checked it ;-). I anyhow would recommend the non-abstract approach, as there are a few advantages to the abstract approach (as you pointed one out).

Comment: Another advantage would be that you do not have to mess with generic relations (http://tiny.cc/7a1vkw), which are actually nice, if you know how to handle them, but makes things a bit more complicated. In the abstract case, a generic relation has to be set to Socket since the ForeignKey relation has to be able to deal with several childs of the Module parent class.